# Can I run two commands with the a single Tkinter menu button?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

If you can see where there's all the topping like bacon, cheese and what not. I'm trying to make that code print ("`bacon selected`") While it saves itself to a list. Can someone aid me in my efforts to make this program print ("`bacon selected`") while it saves to a list.

```
    list = []
    from tkinter import *
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("300x300")

    mb2= Menubutton(root, text = "Choose your toppings ")
    mb2.menu = Menu(mb2)
    mb2["menu"] = mb2.menu   

    bacon = mb2.menu.add_command(label = "bacon", command =  lambda:list.append("Bacon selected") 
    #i want to add another command that prints bacon selected here?

    chesse = mb2.menu.add_command(label = "cheese", command = lambda:list.append("Cheese selected"))

    mb2.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely familiar with TKinter, but you can surely write your own function and pass it to the menu object?

That way you can do multiple things "at once" when a button is pressed:

```
def mybaconfunction():
    list.append("Bacon selected") 
    print("Bacon selected")


bacon = mb2.menu.add_command(label = "bacon", command =  mybaconfunction )
```

Comment: no problem at all. For the next time, dont delete your code after your question has been answered, so others can also find the solution and retrace your steps if they have a similar question :)